# MongoDB positional operator with nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

Sample collection structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57cfd62001ca2dd672cfebb1"),
"name" : "Category",
"parent" : ObjectId("57cfd5d101ca2dd672cfebb0"),
"posts" : [
    {
        "name" : "Post",
        "author" : ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebac"),
        "content" : "Some content.",
        "comments" : [
            {
                "author" : ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebab"),
                "content" : "First comment",
                "rating" : 2
            },
            {
                "author" : ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebac"),
                "content" : "Second comment",
                "rating" : 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I would like to select all `comments` whose `author` is `ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebab")`.

This query is working,

```
db.categories.find({ 'posts.comments.author':ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebab") })
```

but I would like to return only first matching comment with positional operator. Something like this is not working. Does MongoDB support positional operator with nested arrays?

```
db.categories.find({ 'posts.comments.author': ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebab") }, 
{ 'posts.comments.$': 1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having more than two level of nesting ...`find()` may not work ,instead try aggregation:-

```
> db.categories.aggregate([{$unwind:"$posts"},{$unwind:"$posts.comments"},
{$match:{"posts.comments.author":ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebab")}},
{$project:{_id:0,"posts.comments":1}}]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
        "posts" : {
                "comments" : {
                        "author" : ObjectId("57cfd09401ca2dd672cfebab"),
                        "content" : "First comment",
                        "rating" : 2
                }
        }
}
```